# Getting Policy Signing failed error and Received an empty or invalid response from the server! with Fine Uploader Serverless Upload

Tags: angularjs, facebook, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

While attempting to upload files to an s3 bucket, I keep getting "Policy Signing failed error", "Received an empty or invalid response from the server!", and "POST request for 0 has failed - response code 404".  I've followed the tutorial and configured the app via facebook apps, as well as set up Facebook as an ID Provider in AWS IAM Roles.

I can drop files into the box, but the error formulated is: **Received an empty or invalid response from the server!**

Here is my code:

**artwork.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name artvoicesApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the artvoicesApp
 */
angular.module('artvoicesApp')
  .controller('ArtworkCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', 'FIREBASE_URL', 'Auth', '$state', function ($scope, $firebaseObject, FIREBASE_URL, Auth, $state) {

    var artist = FIREBASE_URL.child('data/artists/');
    var artistObject = $firebaseObject(artist);
    var authData = Auth.$getAuth();
    var token = authData.facebook.accessToken;
    $scope.newArt = {};

    artistObject.$loaded().then(function() {
      $scope.artist = artistObject;
    });

    var artwork = FIREBASE_URL.child('data/artists/artwork');
    var artworkObject = $firebaseObject(artwork);

    artworkObject.$loaded().then(function() {
      $scope.artwork = artworkObject;
    });

    $scope.submitNewArt = function() {
      artwork.push({name: $scope.newArt.name, status: $scope.newArt.status, height: $scope.newArt.height, width: $scope.newArt.width, value: $scope.newArt.value});
    };

    $scope.editData = function(data, k, c) { //k is for key, c is for category
      artworkObject[k][c] = data;
      artworkObject.$save().then(function() {}, function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
    };

    $scope.logout = function() {
      Auth.$unauth();
      $state.go('login');
    };

    var s3Globals = {
      userName: authData.facebook.displayName,
      roleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::875128865884:role/facebook-idp-role',
      token: authData.facebook.accessToken
    };


    $(function() {
      var assumeRoleWithWebIdentity = function(params) {
              var sts = new AWS.STS(),
                  assumeRoleParams = {};
              // s3Globals.roleArn = s3Globals.roleArn;
              // s3Globals.providerId = s3Globals.providerId;
               //params.idToken || s3Globals.idToken;

              assumeRoleParams = {
                  ProviderId: 'graph.facebook.com',
                  RoleArn: s3Globals.roleArn,
                  RoleSessionName: "web-identity-federation",
                  WebIdentityToken: s3Globals.token
              };

              // if (s3Globals.providerId) {
              //     assumeRoleParams.ProviderId = s3Globals.providerId;
              // }

              sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(assumeRoleParams, params.callback || s3Globals.updateCredentials);
          },
          getFuCredentials = function(data) {
              return {
                  accessKey: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
                  secretKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                  sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
                  expiration: data.Credentials.Expiration
              };
          };

      s3Globals.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity = assumeRoleWithWebIdentity;
      s3Globals.getFuCredentials = getFuCredentials;
    });

    $(function() {
        var bucketUrl = "https://artvoicestest.s3.amazonaws.com",
            updateCredentials = function(error, data) {
                if (!error) {
                    $('#uploader').fineUploaderS3("setCredentials", s3Globals.getFuCredentials(data));
                }
            };

        $("#uploader").fineUploaderS3({
            request: {
                endpoint: bucketUrl
            },
            objectProperties: {
                // Since we want all items to be publicly accessible w/out a server to return a signed URL
                acl: "public-read",

                //The key for each file will follow this format: {USER_NAME}/{UUID}.{FILE_EXTENSION}
                key: function(id) {
                    var filename = this.getName(id),
                        uuid = this.getUuid(id);

                    return qq.format("{}/{}.{}", s3Globals.userName, uuid, qq.getExtension(filename));
                }
            },
            chunking: {
                enabled: true
            },
            resume: {
                enabled: true
            },
            // Restrict files to 15 MB and 5 net files per session
            validation: {
                itemLimit: 5,
                sizeLimit: 15000000
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    notAvailablePath: "not_available-generic.png",
                    waitingPath: "waiting-generic.png"
                }
            }
        })
            .on('complete', function(event, id, name, response, xhr) {
                var $fileEl = $(this).fineUploaderS3("getItemByFileId", id),
                    $viewBtn = $fileEl.find(".view-btn"),
                    key = $(this).fineUploaderS3("getKey", id);

                // Add a "view" button to access the uploaded file in S3 if the upload is successful
                if (response.success) {
                    $viewBtn.show();
                    $viewBtn.attr("href", bucketUrl + "/" + key);
                }
            })
            .on("credentialsExpired", function() {
                var promise = new qq.Promise();

                // Grab new credentials
                s3Globals.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity({
                    callback: function(error, data) {
                        if (error) {
                            promise.failure("Failed to assume role");
                        }
                        else {
                            promise.success(s3Globals.getFuCredentials(data));
                        }
                    }
                });

                return promise;
            });

        s3Globals.updateCredentials = updateCredentials;
        // $(document).on("tokenReceived.s3", function() {
        //     $("#uploader").show();
        // });
        // $(document).trigger("tokenExpired.s3");
    });

  }]);
```

**index.html**

```
    <script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
        <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
            <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
                <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Upload a file</div>
            </div>
                <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                    <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                    <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
                </span>
            <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
                <li>
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                        <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                    <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Retry</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
                    <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <input type="text">
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script>var s3DemoGlobals = {};</script>


    <!-- endbuild -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      !function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)if(analytics.invoked)window.console&&console.error&&console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{analytics.invoked=!0;analytics.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","page","once","off","on"];analytics.factory=function(t){return function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);e.unshift(t);analytics.push(e);return analytics}};for(var t=0;t<analytics.methods.length;t++){var e=analytics.methods[t];analytics[e]=analytics.factory(e)}analytics.load=function(t){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.async=!0;e.src=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https://":"http://")+"cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/"+t+"/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n)};analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="3.1.0";
      analytics.load("0A4Y3sUzm9iPLwDEcwyLoxaDvicWeiws");
      analytics.page()
      }}();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="artvoicesApp">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <!-- <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" style="text-align: center" href="#/">ArtVoices</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> -->

    <!-- The element where Fine Uploader will exist. -->


    <ui-view></ui-view>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/cloudinary_ng/js/angular.cloudinary.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/animateCSS/dist/jquery.animatecss.js"></script>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.2.35.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fine-uploader/s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js"></script>



    <!-- endbowe->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/artwork.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/auth.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/factories/authfactory.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/factories/login.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

**artwork.html**

*uploader is located at div id="uploader"*

```
<div id="artwork-page" ng-cloak>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
      <p><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1 class="artist-name">{{artist.name}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="add-art-div">
    <a style="color: white" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-target="#add-art" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Art</a>
  </div>
  <div id="stripe-div">

  </div>
  <div class="add-art-modal">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="add-art" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align: center">Add Artwork</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row drag-drop-add">
              <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <div id="uploader"></div>
                <p>Drop Image <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
                <img src="images/audio_file.png" class="drag-image">
                <div id="fine-uploader"></div>

                <p>Drop Audio <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <form name="addArt" ng-submit="submitNewArt()" novalidate>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="exampleInputName2" class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 modal-input">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" ng-required="true" ng-model="newArt.name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="exampleInputValue" class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Value:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 modal-input">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputValue" ng-required="true" ng-model="newArt.value">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="exampleInputStatus" class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Status:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 modal-input">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputStatus" ng-required="true" ng-model="newArt.status">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="exampleInputHeight" class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Height:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 modal-input">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputHeight" ng-required="true" ng-model="newArt.height">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="exampleInputWidth" class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Width:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 modal-input">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputWidth" ng-required="true" ng-model="newArt.width">
                </div>
              </div>
              <p class="warning" ng-show="addArt.$invalid">*All Items must be filled in to Add Item</p>
              <div class="add-art">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary add-art" ng-disabled="addArt.$invalid">Submit Artwork</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-columns">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center" ng-repeat="(key, v) in artwork">
        <div class="card animated" ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false" ng-class="{pulse: hover}">
          <h4 class="card-title art-name">{{v.descriptionText}}</h4>
          <img class="card-img-top artwork" src="{{v.imageUrl}}" alt="Card image cap">
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Status:</strong> <button class="btn btn-normal" onbeforesave="editData($data, key, 'status')" editable-text="v.status">{{ v.status || "empty" }} <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Price:</strong> <button class="btn btn-normal" onbeforesave="editData($data, key, 'value')" editable-text="v.value">${{ v.value || "empty" }} <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Width:</strong> <button class="btn btn-normal" onbeforesave="editData($data, key, 'width')" editable-text="v.width">{{ v.width || "empty" }} <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Height:</strong> <button class="btn btn-normal" onbeforesave="editData($data, key, 'height')" editable-text="v.height">{{ v.height || "empty" }} <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Debug Logs**

```
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Parsing template
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Template parsing complete
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Rendering template in DOM.
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Template rendering complete
    http://localhost:9000/%7B%7Bv.imageUrl%7D%7D Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Received 1 files.
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Attempting to validate image.
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Sending simple upload request for 0
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Submitting S3 signature request for 0
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Sending POST request for 0
    http://localhost:9000/null Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] POST request for 0 has failed - response code 404qq.log @ s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Error attempting to parse signature response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token Cqq.log @ s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Received an empty or invalid response from the server!qq.log @ s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Policy signing failed.  Received an empty or invalid response from the server!qq.log @ s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16
    s3.jquery.fine-uploader.min.js:16 [Fine Uploader 5.5.0] Simple upload request failed for 0
```

Comment: I'll need more information, such as the version of Fine Uploader, and a complete set of logs with the `debug` option set to `true`.

Comment: the version is 5.5.0.  I'll edit the post and post the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that Fine Uploader S3 is trying to send a signature request indicates that you are not providing any sort of credentials either via the options or API before the first file is uploaded. You'll need to set some break points and figure out why temporary credentials are not being provided by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. You are correct. I was attempting to set credentials before the request returned with the temp credentials.  I ended up putting the sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity function into a promise and running the fineUploaderS3 method after resolving the promise.  Here is the code:

**s3Factory.js**

```
angular.module('artvoicesApp')
  .factory('s3Factory', ['$q', function ($q) {

    var s3Object = {};

    s3Object.getTempCredentials = function(s3Globals) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      var assumeRoleParams = {
          RoleArn: s3Globals.roleArn,
          RoleSessionName: "web-identity-federation",
          WebIdentityToken: s3Globals.token
      };
      if (s3Globals.providerId) {
        assumeRoleParams.ProviderId = s3Globals.providerId;
      }
      var sts = new AWS.STS();
      sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(assumeRoleParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); } // an error occurred
        else    { defer.resolve(data);}         // successful response
      });

      return defer.promise;
    };

    s3Object.assignCredentials = function(data) {
          return {
              accessKey: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
              secretKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
              sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
              expiration: data.Credentials.Expiration
          };
    };

    return s3Object;

  }]);
```

**artwork.js**

```
  s3Factory.getTempCredentials(s3Globals).then(function(data) {
    $("#uploader").fineUploaderS3("setCredentials", s3Factory.assignCredentials(data));
  });
```